# using for loop and if statement to check id names with numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, for-loop

```
       for (var i = 1; i < 81; i++){
            if($(this).hasClass('member-'+i)){
                ('promote'+i) = true;
            }
        }
```

I have 80 droppable boxes. They each has an id called member-1, member-2, etc., when someone drags an item into the boxes, the variable will be turned to true and be passed to another function.

So far I found this is not working. I wasn't sure why. It is inside a droppable drop function.

since I have 80 boxes...I don't feel like typing them out manually.

Comment: What do you expect `('promote'+i) = true` to do?

Comment: I expect to pass promote1, promote2 to another function. So when its set to true, something happens

Comment: I actually can't use this way to set variables to true, coz it sets all  to true.
Is there better way to set the unique variable that associated with the class number to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `promote` an array, rather than 80 different variables. Then you can do:

```
   var promote = [];
   for (var i = 1; i < 81; i++){
        if($(this).hasClass('member-'+i)){
            promote[i] = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Much better would be to just see what classes do exist rather than testing for 81 different classes:

```
var matches, promotes = [], cls = this.className;
var regex = /member-(\d+)/g;
while (matches = regex.exec(cls)) {
    // matches[1] contains the number from the member-xx class name
    promotes.push(parseInt(matches[1], 10));
}
// promotes is an array that contain a list of the member-xx numbers that exist
// on this object
```